# How to match question like current or latest

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to model a billing question where the user may ask "What is my *current* bill?", "What is my *latest* bill?", "What is my *previous* bill?" or "What is my bill?".

In the first 2 cases, current, latest identify the most recent bill.  Third case (previous) identifies a previous bill.  Last does not provide a time identifier so I would like to either match it to latest or do some slot filling.

How do I recognize current, latest or previous as identifiers of ordinality? of bills?  What entity type should I use - system or developer?

Answer (score 1):

These sound like they would be good for a Developer Entity where you can have an Entity type of "current" matching things like "current", "latest", "most recent", and "this month" and "previous" matching things like "previous" and "last month".

If you want to, you can also add training phrases such as "What was my bill in February" or "What was my bill two months ago". These might be done as additional training phrases, and possibly even with additional parameters. Your fulfillment can take action based on which parameters are filled in and what those values are.

Remember - Intents capture what the user says, not how you handle what they say.

Comment: True that but then we have a situation where a person does not provide a "time" descriptor (What is my bill?) which could default to "current".  What about a statement like "What was my bill 2 months ago?".  Doe that mean that now we woudl not match to the developer Entity of "current" or "previous" but rather go with a date system entity which would match "2 months ago"?